# IIS 6 asks for authentication when using hostname

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-6, windows-authentication

We have a website to which we have now added Windows authenication. Now when I release my changes to the server,IIS asks for Authenication, and after trying with right credentials for 3 times, I get Not autorized error.

If I try to access the website from within the server using localhost, it works fine. It also works fine if accessed remotely using IP address instead of hostname.

http://localhost/mysite works fine from within the server EXSER002.
http://IPADDRESS/mysite works fine 
http://EXSER002/mysite fails with authentication.

The site use to work with the hostname prior to Windows authentication.

Even tried ping from local machine to the server and I can ping both the hostname as well as the IP address. Error I get is: You are not authorized to view this page

Comment: In all three of your tests in the user logged in as the same account?

Comment: do you get a specific error code, 40?.?

Comment: Yes logged in as same user. Even tried ping from local machine to the server and I can ping both the hostname as well as the IP address.  Error I get is: You are not authorized to view this page

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a proxy? If so, make sure that bypass is on for local addresses.

Comment: I have checked bypass is on for local addresses. The site worked fine using hostname before Windows authentication was put in place.

Comment: When you ping the name, do you get the FQN back? does the domain part match the machine's domain match? (the browsing machine)

Comment: If you can get to the sites iis logs you should get be able to see more about the authentication error from the codes 40?.?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 . 
The issue occurs due to the loopback check security feature .you need to make registry setting changes (as mentioned in the link) to get rid of the authentication failures.